# ASUS Q-LED, how to use it?

Tags: motherboard

I just bought a ROG STRIX B350-F, and one of the features is "Q-LED". From ASUS' website:

> When there's a problem with your PC, quickly being able to diagnose
>   and remedy the issue can eliminate a great deal of frustration. ASUS
>   Q-LED immediately indicates when there's a problem with the CPU,
>   memory, graphics card or boot device by lighting up in the vicinity of
>   that component.

The trouble is the manual has no information at all for how to use this: https://dlsvr04.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/STRIX_B350-F_GAMING/E12721_ROG_STRIX_B350-F_GAMING_UM_WEB.PDF

How can we get any benefit from this with no information on how to use it?

Comment: Q-Codes are mostly universal for a manufacturer, so check here: https://www.asus.com/US/support/FAQ/1010872

Comment: Thanks, but I can't even find the codes anywhere on my mobo... I see pictures on Google for other mobo's, but I can't find anything for my own B350-F

Comment: you don't see the LED display? it should be square and about 1/2 inch per side, with two digital numeric digits (like an alarm clock display). upon successful boot it shoudl display somthing like 'FF'. if you don't see it, then your motherboard doesn't have one. sometimes they package several skus of  motherboards with the same manual or packaging, so perhaps thats why your manual in particular didn't discuss it.

Comment: Aah, I think I get it now. The motherboard has Q-LED, and Q-LED is NOT the same as Q-Code which I thought it was.

Comment: the q-code is the value. if my boot stops and hangs while it says `32` then I know that the issue is with 'CPU post-memory initialization'.

Comment: I can only find 4x LEDs that seems to indicate something about certain hardware parts. There is no value or display anywhere on the motherboard.